# Google Analytics: Why goal flow pageviews amount is different from site content one?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics I set a Goal that is a simple URL Destination using a real (not virtual) page url of my site.

The number of Pageviews I can see for this goal in Conversions/Goals/Goal Flow is about 50% of the number of Pageviews reported for the page url (the one I used to set the goal in URL Destination) in Content/Site Content.

I wonder if this is correct and why? Shouldn't the numer of Pageviews in Goal Flow and the number of Pageviews in Content be the same if they refer to the same url? Or, maybe, in Goal Flow Unique Pageview is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because google analytics will track only one Goal conversion per session,
that's why the number of page views is higher then goal conversions.

[look at the first answer in this forum, his explanation is good](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/Oq1L50Q3Fos)